# expose port inside docker at docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I just want to expose port 5555 which is bind to celery flower, to host ip and the port.Could someone please help on this?

Below is some part of dockerfile.

## Make port 80 available to the world outside this container

EXPOSE 5555

## Define environment variable

ENV NAME worker-app

## create paths

RUN /etc/init.d/celeryd create-paths

## clear symfony app cache

RUN cd /srv/clickhq/ && rm -rf var/cache/*

RUN chown -R lighthouse:lighthouse /srv/clickhq/

## clear php app cache

USER lighthouse
RUN cd /srv/clickhq/ && ./clearcache.sh

## Start celeryd, celerybeat and php-fpm services when the container launches

> Blockquote

```
USER root
RUN chown -R lighthouse:lighthouse /var/run/celery/ && chown -R lighthouse:lighthouse /var/log/celery/
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/log/celery/ && chmod -R 755 /var/run/celery/
RUN chown -R lighthouse:lighthouse /srv/clickhq/
ENTRYPOINT sudo service celeryd start && sudo service celerybeat start && service php7.0-fpm start && service rsyslog start && /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flower -A celery --broker=redis://password@192.168.51.4:6379/0 && bash
```

> Blockquote

Docker run command Im using is

```
"sudo docker run -it --rm --name worker-app -d worker-app --privileged -p 192.168.51.3:5555:5555 --net="bridge"
```

Comment: -p 80:5555 is enough not required IP.

Comment: But it shows as below. 

root@workerapp:/srv/clickhq# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6be26fa92f1f        worker-app          "/bin/sh -c 'sudo se…"   3 seconds ago       Up 1 second         5555/tcp            worker

"It should bind like this ryt ?

0.0.0.0:80->5555/tcp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are really not passing the argument `-p 80:5555` to `docker run`, but to the entrypoint.

In this command `sudo docker run -it --rm --name worker-app -d worker-app --privileged -p 192.168.51.3:5555:5555 --net="bridge"`, worker-app is the image name, so everything after it (`--privileged -p 192.168.51.3:5555:5555 --net="bridge"`) is a parameter for the entrypoint.

It should work if you change the image name to the end:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name worker-app -d --privileged -p 80:5555 --net="bridge worker-app
```

Comment: Is below command is correct ? "sudo docker run -it --rm -p 5555:5555 --name worker-app -d worker-app"

Comment: Yes it is, as -p is before the docker image

Comment: I just want to run below command in shell script at the entrypoint. Could you please tell me how to do it ?

"/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flower -A celery --broker=redis://password@192.168.51.4:6379/0"

I did it in shell script like below. But it doesn't work.

#!/bin/sh

cd ~
exec /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flower -A celery --broker=redis://password@192.168.51.4:6379/0

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT["/bin/sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flower -A celery --broker=redis://password@192.168.51.4:6379/0"]`

Comment: How to do it for this ?

"ENTRYPOINT sudo service celeryd start && sudo service celerybeat start && service php7.0-fpm start && service rsyslog start && /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flower -A celery --broker=redis://password@192.168.51.4:6379/0 && bash"

Comment: Just use the same pattern: `ENTRYPOINT["/bin/sh", "-c", "<ANY BASH COMMAND>"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173463/discussion-between-user3849082-and-ignacio-millan).

Comment: this entrypoint doesn't seem to be working

"ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo service celeryd start", "sudo service celerybeat start", "service php7.0-fpm start", "service rsyslog start", "/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/flower -A celery --broker=redis://password@192.168.51.4:6379/0"]"

what could be the issue ?